# Laravel eager load nested queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a CRM application in Laravel.

We have `User`, `Lead` models.
each User can have sub-users (we call them `Agents`, and the parent is user is `Manager`)
It's a `Many-to-Many` relation defined in `User` model.

```php
// Managers relation
public function managers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'manager_agent', 'agent_id', 'manager_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->using(ManagerAgent::class)
        ->wherePivot('manager_id', '!=', $this->id)
        ->as('manager_agent_pivot');
}

// Agents relation
public function agents(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'manager_agent', 'manager_id', 'agent_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->using(ManagerAgent::class)
        ->wherePivot('agent_id', '!=', $this->id)
        ->as('manager_agent_pivot');
}
```

---

Now, a `User` can have many `Lead`s, and also a `Lead` can belong to to many `User`s (`Many-to-Many`)

The challenge is:
A Manager should be able to see leads that belong to him, also leads that belongs to any of the sub-agents.

With this, I want to get the `Users` (including all nested Manager and Lead) those can see the `Lead`.

So, I wrote this nested query:

```php
// By passing $leadId Get users who can see the lead,
// no matter directly related or lead belongs to any sub-agent.
$users = User::whereHas('leads', function ($query) use ($leadId) {
    $query->where('id', $leadId)
        ->orWhereHas('users.managers.leads', function ($query) use ($leadId) {
            $query->where('id', $leadId);
        });
})->get();
```

It works perfectly, but now I want to eager load the users list for multiple `Lead` just like a relation eager loading.

I just want to get all users eager loaded with the `Lead`.
I have no idea what to do, would be great if someone can guide me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// By passing $leadId Get users who can see the lead,
// no matter directly related or lead belongs to any sub-agent.
$users = User::withWhereHas('leads', function ($query) use ($leadId) {
    $query->where('id', $leadId)
        ->orWhereHas('users.managers.leads', function ($query) use ($leadId) {
            $query->where('id', $leadId);
        });
    $query->with('users');
})->get();
```